# How can I log to the same file from multiple files and loggers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am trying to implement the following logging pattern in my application:

Shared method in a 'HelperFunctions.py' file to create loggers:

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file_name, format_str=constants.debug_log_format, level=logging.DEBUG):
    """Create loggers -- Daily log format by default"""

    formatter = logging.Formatter(format_str)
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file_name, 'midnight', 1, 14)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

In 'script_one.py':

```
logger = HelperFunctions.setup_logger('scriptOneLogger', './logs/scriptOne/dailyLog.log')
logger_cmn = HelperFunctions.setup_logger('cmnLogger', './logs/scriptOne/dailyLog.log')

logger.info('Hello from script_one')
```

In 'script_two.py':

```
logger = HelperFunctions.setup_logger('scriptTwoLogger', './logs/scriptTwo/dailyLog.log')
logger_cmn = HelperFunctions.setup_logger('cmnLogger', './logs/scriptTwo/dailyLog.log')

logger.info('Hello from script_two')
```

In 'db_utils.py':

```
logger_one = logging.getLogger('scriptOneLogger.dbUtils')
logger_two = logging.getLogger('scriptTwoLogger.dbUtils')
logger_cmn = logging.getLogger('cmnLogger.dbUtils')

def only_called_from_script_one():
    logger_one.info('This should be in the daily log for script one.')

def only_called_from_script_two():
    logger_two.info('This should be in the daily log for script two.')

def can_be_called_from_either():
    logger_cmn.info('This should appear in the log of whatever script called it.')
```

In 'network_utils.py':

```
logger_cmn = logging.getLogger('cmnLogger.networkUtil')

# these functions can all be called from any script

def can_be_called_from_anywhere():
    logger_cmn.info('This should appear in the log of whatever script called it.')
```

Right now, with the above setup, I'm seeing some inconsistent results. One of two things seems to be happening:

- The current days log file works as expected, showing logs from each logger in the right file, but the back ups for previous days only show one or the other.
- The current day also only shows logs from one logger or the other.

How can I get them to show logs from all loggers always (in the current day and archived logs)?